# SSH forwarding: Connect to SSH tunnel on clientside the right way

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

SSH from Client to Server via SSH Tunnels - please help.

Remote SERVER S1, a VPS SERVER S2 with SSH on SSHPORT2, a CLIENT C1 (where I'm typing right now).

S1 is forwarding ssh via autossh to S2:

`S1# autossh -p $SSHPORT2 -R $REMPORT1:localhost:22 s2user@S2`

So SSH is available at $REMPORT1. I can connect to SSH of S1 on S2 via

`S2# ssh -p $REMPORT1 s1user@localhost`

Right now, I'm connecting to this on SSH Tunnel on C1 per

`C1# ssh -p $SSHPORT2 -L $LOCALC1PORT:localhost:$REMPORT1 s2user@S2`

and after that

`C1# ssh -p $LOCALC1PORT s1user@localhost`

is there anything I can do to "reduce" this on my Client (like in ONE ssh command)?

Looking forward to hear from you